# Set x mirror as default in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting, startup-file

So I set up a default start up file for sculpting with x mirror set as on in but as symmetry is no longer  default for sculpt mode when I start a sculpt with a second object it is set to off which can occassionally be frustrating when I realise too late. Is there any way to set it as on as default?
thanks